# How to create simple Web Server for Map/Java Application?

Tags: java, web, webserver

I want to create web server for (localhost) which:
1-provides HTML code (https://leafletjs.com/)
2-receives requests (Ajax requests) from the client that calls corresponding methods in the backend and their send the result back to the client.

Comment: What is your question? I only see that you want to build a webServer. There are many technologies that allow this. .Net,Angular,Servlets... Ajax requests are just java script requests sent to the server.

Comment: Your question isn't very coherent. I would suggest looking into SpringBoot as that makes it really easy to get a REST web server up and running.

Comment: I want to build a web based map planner. I have implemented the backend with Java. Now i want to do the Frontend.

Comment: What is "simple"? We cannot answer that question without knowing what you are already familiar with and what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Install an "Apache Tomcat" application server and write a "Servet Application" or use "Java Server Faces". Google for those keywords.

I wrote a german tutorial about this: http://stefanfrings.de/jsf_tutorial/index.html there is a translation link in the upper right corner.

If you do not want to install an application server, then you may prefer to use Jetty, which is basically the same as Tomcat but embedded in your own executable program.